# Javascript Module Pattern with anonymous functions

Tags: javascript, anonymous-function

I'm understanding the principle of module pattern but when I look at the different definition I struggle to understand how anonymous functions work. In particular, takes those three examples

Example 1, (from http://viralpatel.net/blogs/javascript-module-pattern/)

```
CalcModule = (function(){
                var pub = {};
                pub.add = function(a, b) {
                             console.log('in add()', a, b);
                             return a + b;
                };
                pub.sub = function(a, b) {
                             console.log('in sub()', a, b);
                             return a - b;
                };
                return pub;
})();
```

which is used as

```
CalcModule.add(5,2) //returns : 7
```

Example 2 (from Learning JavaScript Design Patterns 1.5.2, Addy Osmani)

```
var testModule = (function () {

  var counter = 0;

  return {

    incrementCounter: function () {
      return counter++;
    },

    resetCounter: function () {
      console.log( "counter value prior to reset: " + counter );
      counter = 0;
    }
  };
})();
```

which is used as

```
testModule.incrementCounter()
```

Example 3 (from http://css-tricks.com/how-do-you-structure-javascript-the-module-pattern-edition/)

```
var s,
NewsWidget = {

  settings: {
    numArticles: 5,
    articleList: $("#article-list"),
    moreButton: $("#more-button")
  },

  init: function() {
    // kick things off
    s = this.settings;
  }
};
```

which, by the way, I don't know ho to use it.

As you see, the methods, for example add, incrementCounter and init are defined in different ways:

- Example 1: by means of a private variable pub
- Example 2: in the return method!
- Example 3: as method of the constructor NewsWidget

Question: In my mind Example 3 is what I would do and I don't understand why Example 1 and 2 are not used in the following way

- Example 1: CalcModule.pub.add(5,2)
- Example 2: no idea

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like you need to understand how `return` works in functions in order to understand why the provided examples behave the way they do.

**Example 1:** You create a new variable `pub` and adding two methods to it: `add` and `sub`.  At the end, you're *returning* the pub variable to `CalcModule`

So when you call `CalcModule`, it returns the following object with two methods:

```
CalcModule = {
   add: function() {...},
   sub: function() {...}
}
```

**Example 2:** Let's rewrite example 2 similar to example 1...

```
var testModule = (function () {

  var counter = 0;
  var pub;

  pub.incrementCounter: function () {
      return counter++;
  }

  pub.resetCounter: function () {
      console.log( "counter value prior to reset: " + counter );
      counter = 0;
  }

  return pub;
})();
```

We know `pub` is an object...

```
pub = {
   incrementCounter: function() { ... },
   resetCounter: function() { ... }
}
```

and we're returning `pub` to `testModule`...  therefore...

```
testModule = {
   incrementCounter: function() {...},
   resetCounter: function() {...}
}
```

Hope this is helpful.

Comment: So, is your Example 2 totally equivalent to my Example 2? I think I'm starting to understand. Thanks

Comment: @user2279697 That's correct, my example 2 is exactly the same as your example 2. Both of our examples return an object {}. The only difference is that my object is stored in a variable `pub`, and I'm returning back the value of `pub` (which is an object) -- whereas you're just returning the object directly.  Try `var str = "hello world"; return str;` and `return "hello world"` -- they both do the same.

Answer (score 0):

In example 1, `pub` is assigned to the variable `CalcModule` via the return statement and the assignment of the return value so `CalcModule` becomes an alias for `pub` directly.  That's why it's `CalcModule.add()`.  That value that is returned from the IIFE `return pub;` gets assigned to `CalcModule`.  It's as if one did `CalcModule = pub`.

In example two, `testModule` is assigned an unnamed object via the return value and that object has the methods `incrementCounter()` and `resetCounter()`.  So, again `testModule` becomes a named alias for that object so you can then refer to the methods in that object as `testModule.incrementCounter()` and `testModule.resetCounter()`.

Example 1 as shown has no advantage over Example 3 so if you are more comfortable with Example 3, then that's fine.  Your Example 3 has a variable `s` that seems a bit odd and out of character because you're setting a global variable when `NewsWidget.init()` is called which is usually not a good design pattern.  Perhaps you want to return that value from `.init()`.

Example 2 is using the IIFE (immediately invoked function expression) to create a safe and private place to store the `counter` variable that is not in the global namespace, cannot conflict with any other code and cannot be access by other code example your own methods.  This is essentially a way to create a "private" variable that only your methods can access.  Example 1 could have also used that capability, but your Example 3 does not have the option to use that capability because it doesn't have the enclosing IIFE.

Comment: You took a good point! Would Example 2 lose the advantages that you listed above if I would declare it as: var myFun = function (a) {....}; and var testModule = new function(a); ?

Answer (score 0):

The important part is to understand functions are first class citizen in JavaScript. Which means functions can be passed around and assigned to variables just like any other objects, so is modules.

In your first example, 2 functions (*pub.add, pub.sub*) as created as members of module *pub*, and then assigned to variable *CalcModule*

In second example, return variable is returning an *object literal*, which has two key/value pairs, with keys being function name and values being functions. assigning that object literal is equivalent to make the variable assigned as 2 member functions, which is creating namespace